# ggsurvplot: unable to use survfit when called from a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a survival plot and have run into an issue when trying to move my survfit function into a main function, where I can call it for different data sets. When I run the code

```
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

allsurv <- function(fit){
ggsurvplot(
fit,
pval = TRUE,
pval.coord = c(200, 0.10), 
conf.int = TRUE,
xlab = "Days",
ggtheme = theme_light(), 
surv.median.line = "hv", 
legend.labs = c("Female","Male"),
legend.title = "",
palette = c("#8C3F4D","#3E606F")) + 
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.02, 0.02),breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.1),labels=percent) + 
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.006, 0.006),
                   limits = c(0,366*12), breaks = seq(0, 4392, 100))
}

allsurv(fit)
```

The function is plotted normally [image]

However when I call survfit from a function:

```
fit_all <- function(x){
 survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = x)
}

allsurv(fit_all(lung))
```

I receive an error: " Error in eval(fit$call$data) : object 'x' not found "

Any ideas to what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Survminer includes a function `surv_fit` that acts as a wrapper around `survfit`. If you use `surv_fit` instead of `survfit`, the "call" of the returned object will include the whole data frame instead of just `data = x`. That works better when calling ggsurvplot inside a function:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survminer/versions/0.4.6/topics/surv_fit

```
allsurv <- function(fit){
ggsurvplot(
fit,
pval = TRUE,
pval.coord = c(200, 0.10), 
conf.int = TRUE,
xlab = "Days",
ggtheme = theme_light(), 
surv.median.line = "hv", 
legend.labs = c("Female","Male"),
legend.title = "",
palette = c("#8C3F4D","#3E606F"))
}

fit_all <- function(x){
 surv_fit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = x)
}

allsurv(fit_all(lung))
```

Comment: This just solved my 90+ min of frustration, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it to work. For anyone else with the same issue. The problem seems to be caused by what calling the function on its own or from a different function returns.

```
 fit_all(lung)
```

which returns Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = x)

```
fit
```

which returns Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

It seems that ggsurvplot treats the data in the call as the data for the plot and when called from another function ' data = x'. It seems the way to get past that is to define the data before the survfit function in the ggsurvplot.

```
allsurv <- function(fit, x){
ggsurvplot(
data = x,
fit,
pval = TRUE,
pval.coord = c(200, 0.10), 
conf.int = TRUE,
xlab = "Days",
ggtheme = theme_light(), 
surv.median.line = "hv", 
legend.labs = c("Female","Male"),
legend.title = "",
palette = c("#8C3F4D","#3E606F")) + 
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.02, 0.02),breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.1),labels=percent) + 
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.006, 0.006),
                   limits = c(0,366*12), breaks = seq(0, 4392, 100))
}

allsurv(fit_all(lung), lung)
```